# is it possible to patch ec2 instances based on a schedule through a python script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, patch

I have no code at the moment, but I am wondering where I can be able to look into to learn how to write a python script that will trigger a patching command on an ec2 instance. Patching should be automated using API calls and boto3 as well, but I am having trouble seeing how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to patch using a Python script specifically, take a look at create a [CloudWatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) with an [event schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html). The target could be a [SSM Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) to execute the Python script on each server (if that's how it works).

You can either create your own document or use the `AWS-RunShellScript` document.

**Alternatively**, AWS does have support for automated patching built into by using the [SSM Patch Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-patch.html) which can handle the patching for you.